# Automatically provisioning EC2 instances with tls private keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

I have a mandate to encrypt traffic between services running on AWS EC2 instances, presumably with TLS.  My (current) question is:  how do I get the private key files onto my instances automatically (e.g. when using auto-scaling or spot instances)?  There seem to be a number of options, but at least some of them seem red herrings:

- In https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_server-certs.html, it looks like you can upload certificates and private keys to IAM, but then you can't download the private keys.
- With AWS Certificate Manager, it looks like the private keys are only available to certain services, not EC2 instances (https://serverfault.com/questions/947057/install-aws-ssl-certificate-to-ec2-instance-without-load-balancer).
- Is there some other service I can use (Key Manangement Service, Secrets Manager, etc.)?
- Can I use instance metadata?
- Is there a way to safely store the private keys on the AMIs?
- Is SSL/TLS offload (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/latest/userguide/ssl-offload.html) the best way to go?  It seems complicated and subject to network latency issues.

How can (and how should) I do this?

Comment: You mention you want to get the keys on your EC2 instance "safely". What do you want to protect against? The easiest way is usually to add a Load Balancer to your architecture to do the SSL/TLS handling, even if it's only backed by a single instance. This assumes you trust the AWS-network (hence my question on your thread model)

Comment: @Niobos Apparently we don't trust the AWS network, or at least not the connections between the load balancer and the EC2 instances and between EC2 instances.  Kinda belt and suspenders.

Comment: If you don't trust the AWS network, your options are very limited: You can't store it on-disk, since the disk is also accessed via the AWS-network. You can't use Instance Metadata, since that also travels over the untrusted network. SSL-offloading also sends decrypted data over the network. KMS, parameter store and/or secrets manager seems like options, depending on what else you don't trust.

Comment: UPDATE: I've since realized that we basically consider the AWS network to be trustworthy *most of the time*, and so by adding our own encryption on top of their security we reduce the odds of sending un-encrypted sensitive information when their security is compromised.  Trustworthiness isn't really an either-or sort of thing.